# Can not run GlassFish as a service

Tags: windows, service, glassfish

I'm trying to [run](http://www.luv2code.com/2013/11/13/install-glassfish-4-as-a-windows-service/) GlassFish as service on Windows.

> The domain1 GlassFish Server on Local Computer started and then
>   stopped. Some services stop automatically

Also console says:

> NET HELPMSG 3534

What is wrong?

Comment: You should check if the ports (8080 and 4848) are occupied.

Comment: I run `C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a -b`. No 8080 or 4848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is windows service problem, follow these steps, I hope this will help you:

1)Click **Run** Command from start button

2)Enter **Services.msc** then click **OK**,you will get all the services in your computer.

3)Select your **service** and right click on the service and select **Properties**

4)Goto **Logon Properties** à select  **Local System Account** then click **OK**

And of course you must set Java Path in Environment Variables and JAVA_HOME variable

After all this steps restart computer, if this steps will not help, open **domain1Service.xml** with notepad and copy here