# Error while start Glassfish service

Tags: windows, service, glassfish

I'm creating a Glassfish service, but while I try to start, the following error appears:

> The domain1 GlassFish Server on Local Computer started and then
>   stopped. Some services stop automatically

Console:

> NET HELPMSG 3534

My domain1Service.xml:

```
<service>
<id>Glassfish</id>
  <name>domain1 GlassFish Server</name>
  <description>GlassFish Server</description>
  <executable>C:/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin.bat</executable>
  <logpath>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\domains/domain1/bin</logpath>
  <logmode>reset</logmode>
  <depend>tcpip</depend>
  <startargument>start-domain</startargument>
  <startargument>--verbose</startargument>
     <startargument>--domaindir</startargument>
  <startargument>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\domains</startargument>
<startargument>domain1</startargument>
  <stopargument>stop-domain</stopargument>
     <stopargument>--domaindir</stopargument>
  <stopargument>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\domains</stopargument>
<stopargument>domain1</stopargument>
</service>
```

I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544833/can-not-run-glassfish-as-a-service), but without success.

Comment: Please check the server log to see what errors are logged when you try to start the server. Can you successfully start the server using asadmin in a cmd window? I.e. not as a service?

Comment: When I try to start, nothing appears in the server.log. I can start using asadmin (startserv).

Comment: That helps us rule out GlassFish as the source of the problem. The service isn't even getting to the part where it starts the service.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have the same problem with glassfish service and I found the solution with Going to Windows Services , My Service (here Glassfish(Service)) and than into properties in tab Login on I choose This account and put Account that have administrator rights than put the password on them after that click on start service , My service work fine and than restart the Pc(Server) and work!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your executable path contains forward slashes, which Windows doesn't like. Change them to double backslashes to match the other paths in the xml file.

From this:

```
 <id>Glassfish</id>
   <name>domain1 GlassFish Server</name>
   <description>GlassFish Server</description>
   <executable>C:/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin.bat</executable>
   <logpath>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\domains/domain1/bin</logpath>
   <logmode>reset</logmode>
   <depend>tcpip</depend>
...
```

To this:

```
 <id>Glassfish</id>
   <name>domain1 GlassFish Server</name>
   <description>GlassFish Server</description>
   <executable>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\bin\\asadmin.bat</executable>
   <logpath>C:\\glassfish-3.1.1\\glassfish3\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\bin</logpath>
   <logmode>reset</logmode>
   <depend>tcpip</depend>
...
```

Comment: I changed all slashes: 
<startargument>start-domain</startargument>  
<startargument>--verbose</startargument>
     <startargument>--domaindir</startargument>  
  <startargument>C:/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish3/glassfish/domains</startargument>
<startargument>domain1</startargument>                                                  

But still not working

Comment: Looks like you changed the wrong ones. See my edit for an example.

Comment: Now the slashes are correct, but still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same behaviour as before? Are there any entries in the server.log now? Can you be sure that your changes have been picked up by the service?

Comment: Can you also open up cmd prompt and type `NET HELPMSG 3534` (or whatever number it says when you try to start it) and paste what it says here?

Comment: I checked the server.log, but not this writing it. What appears when I type  `NET HELPMSG 3534` is `The service did not report an error.`
Can be a windows problem ? I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm no Windows admin, but I would expect that the number 3534 is the process ID of the service when you tried to start it, so it could have changed by now.